# junk values are getting inserted in to map

Tags: c++

I am trying a to eliminate duplicates that are stored in a file by inserting the values read from file into a C++ map. 
Input:

1 1
2 3

Below is the logic:

```
do
{
    ret = read(fd, (void*)&value, 1);
    if(ret != -1 && ret != 0 && value != 10 && value != 32 )
    {
            insertVal = value - 48;
            cout<<"value computed " << insertVal << endl;
            if(numArr[insertVal] == 0)
                numArr[insertVal] = 100;
    }
    insertVal = 0;

}while(ret!= 0);
```

output:

```
value computed 1
value computed 1
value computed 2
value computed 3
```

Instead array if I use map,

logic is changed to

```
do
{
    ret = read(fd, (void*)&value, 1);
    if(ret != -1 && ret != 0 && value != 10 && value != 32 )
    {
            insertVal = value - 48;
            cout<<"value computed " << insertVal << endl;
            numberMap.insert(std::pair<int, int>(insertVal, 100));
    }
    insertVal = 0;

}while(ret!= 0);
```

output:

> `value computed 4200410  value computed 4200449  value computed    4200432  value computed 4200449  value computed 4200410  value    computed 4200450  value computed 4200432  value computed 4200451     value computed 4200410`

My question is, why map insertion is making value to junk. Please help me with this.

Comment: It's not the insertion, the value is chunk beforehands (at the output)

Comment: This is incoherent. What types are `value`, `insertVal`, `ret`, `numArr` ? Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If the rest of the code is the same, the type of container shouldn't affect the output at all unless you're suffering from undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over complicating things. A simple way to read into a `std::map` will be

```
std::map<int, int> numberMap;
std::ifstream fd("file_name");
...
for (int value; fd >> value;) {
    if (value == 10 || value == 32) continue;
    int insertVal = value - 48;
    numberMap[insertVal] = 100;
}
```

Comment: This performs formatted extraction, which is substantially different from the original code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The input file has a series of integers, which this code is reading one by one. What is different ?

Comment: it worked with one change. (I removed -48) But have you tried with 'open' and 'read'. I felt, rather using wrappers for file operations, I want to try with system calls. There I ended up getting such huge values like 4200410, 4200449 ...

Comment: @user5096953 The values suggest that variables you are using may have been uninitialized or incorrectly used with the system calls. Read the documentation carefully before using them directly.